# Apple Touch Icon Home Screen Fails

Tags: iphone, favicon, homescreen

Having read how to add a custom home screen icon for my web app, I have spent days trying to make it work and whatever I do, the `Add to Home Screen` process results in an icon based on the screen shot of the current web page.

- I have tried using the default file names alone
- I have tried using the `<link rel="" href="">` definitions and the icons
- I have tried putting the icons in the root directory and one level down
- I have tried 57x57, 72x72 and 114x114 sized icons, with and without the sizes definition
- I have tried precomposed and normal with and without the corresponding change to the rel name

But whatever I do the `Add to Home Screen` process on my iPhone 4 running iOS 6.3 ignores whatever icon I define and gives me a screen shot based icon. I am tearing my hair out.

How can I find what is going wrong? How do I debug this process to find what is wrong? I have mobile safari linked to safari on the desktop to see what is going on but I am none the wiser.

Comment: iOS 6.3? did you mean 6.1.3?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some meta definitions. For example this works in our web apps. Check that the png you're using is valid image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/appicon-57.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/appicon-72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/appicon-114.png" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>
<body>
...
```